# NodeJS- Cannot install nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am trying to install nodemon but everytime I got stuck at the same part.
It get a response, but didn't end the job. 
I have to stop it after some minutes with the state bellow.
I already try another modules and all of them install correctaly.

Could someone say what could be wrong or any other similar module?
Thanks.

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.28 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\>npm instal -g nodemon
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
```

Comment: any solution? i'm facinf the same problem

Comment: Shouldn't be 'install' instead of 'instal' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it but I installed from the source and I did a git clone from the master branch, so try this out:

Create a folder:

```
mkdir nodemon
cd nodemon
```

clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/remy/nodemon.git
```

then do an install in the folder you have created

```
npm install
```

Type **nodemon** just to make sure you have installed it.

in the case you got an erorr like this

> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/[username]/.config/configstore/update-notifier-nodemon.yml'
>   You don't have access to this file.

try this

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] /home/[username]/.config/configstore/ -R
```

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me with other modules after canceling the install mid-way once, then when I do it again, it will get stuck.

I had to clear the cache before trying again.

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g nodemon
```